# Google Apps Script Async function execution on Server side

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have a GMail add-on which uses CardService for UI. Some of the callback functions for the Card actions take over than 30 sec. Thus, I'm getting the following error.

> Gmail could not perform this add-on action.

Is there, any way to run Google Apps Script functions on the Server side asynchronous way, so I can return to a user some notification and continue work behind the scenes.

I have tried using some libraries like this [one](https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/promisesappsscript) but with no luck, I'm able to use syntactically the Promises but functionally it's still synchronous.

Comment: Without seeing examples of what you're doing, all we can offer is that you should improve your backend operations through the use of [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service) and [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to avoid expensive computations.  Note that libraries and globals are evaluated **every time** your add on runs **any** function, so they are generally discouraged for add-ons.

Comment: @Ruben Thanks for the comment. I think I would need to re-design my backend computations at the end. However, the purpose of my question was to be sure that there is no way to do something asynchronously on the Server side, perhaps something was changed recently from GAS side or something like that.

Comment: The comment was made by @tehhowch :)

Comment: @Rubén Sorry :) Got confused with the edit

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there is no asynchronous execution for the Gmail add-on. Even if there is something, there is no way to refresh the UI without user action.

But, there is a hack. What you can do is, if there is a long running process is there, just create a "openlink" action (set link), which should open a url (https://yourhtmlpageurl?redirect_uri=) with html response. This html can have jquery ajax call, which can wait for some time. Once you get the response in the html window, redirect the page to the redirect_uri that is passed by passing the response data. So, our add on will get a callback to the function with parameter as json object with all the query parameters to the redirect_uri. Once you get the expected response, cache the response by using [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service). return some html success template, which should automatically close the window by itself.

For Creating **openlink** action:

For generating redirect script URI with state token:

```
function generateNewStateToken(callbackName, user_info) {
return ScriptApp.newStateToken()
.withMethod(callbackName)
.withArgument("user_info", JSON.stringify(user_info))
.withTimeout(3600)
.createToken();
}

function getRedirectURI() {
    return "https://script.google.com/macros/d/" + ScriptApp.getScriptId() + "/usercallback";
}

var htmlUrl = <your_html_url> + "?redirect_uri="+ getRedirectURI() + "&state=" + generateNewStateToken("asyncCallback", {});

CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl(htmlUrl).setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY).setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON);

function asyncCallback(data) {
    data.response; // response which you can pass from script
    CacheService.getUserCache().put("long_running_process_resp", data.response);
    data.user_info; // user_info passed during state token creation
    // cache the data using cache service
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("success");
}
```

**success.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>Long running Process completed.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    top.window.close();
  }, 2000);
  </script>
</html>
```

Once the success.html is closed by itself, there will be a refresh of the gmail add on. So, you can lookup for the long running response data from CacheService.

Let me know if you have any more questions on this process.

Answer (score 0):

Sabbu's answer is pretty good. But, if you want to trigger the long running process without expecting the user to click on the openlink, you can render an image using:
CardService.newImage().setImageUrl('https://yourservice.com/pixel/action.png?name=value&_nocache='+new Date().getTime())

On the server side, you can map the path '/pixel/action.png' to the long running code which returns a tiny transparent pixel (1x1) on complete:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==